# App crashes from changing volume, states KVO message was received but not handled for keypath "outputVolume"

Tags: swift, debugging, key-value-observing, avaudiosession

My app crashes anytime I change the volume. It tells me I am not handling a notification from AVAudioSession but I have setup the observer for this and set a breakpoint to ensure that it is indeed being handled.

```
    var kvoVolumeObs: NSKeyValueObservation?

    func observe() {
    kvoVolumeObs = audioSession.observe(\.outputVolume, options: [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (session, change) in
         print("volume for session \(session.outputVolume)")
        if let player = self.player {
            player.setVolume(session.outputVolume)
        }
    })
}
```

Maybe I'm not handling it in the correct place?

I'm setting the AVAudioSession as active in my AVPlayer class, but I wouldn't expect that to initiate a KVO call.

```
    func startAudioSession() {
    backgroundSessionKillTimer?.invalidate()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: AVAudioSession.SetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to set AudioSession Stuff \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I've been working on this for a while with no solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The debug statement for the crash is below.

```
2020-09-28 08:00:11.082153-0600 98.5 KYGO[1507:259676] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<CFRunLoopSource 0x1044d1840 [0x1e13d5b40]>{signalled = No, valid = Yes, order = 0, context = <SCNetworkReachability RLS> {target = 0x10bcf8f80}}: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: outputVolume
Observed object: <AVAudioSession: 0x10444d5a0>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 1;
}
Context: 0x0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x193951114 0x1a7177cb4 0x194bc8f84 0x194bc90a4 0x194bcb4d8 0x194bc88d0 0x19adc869c 0x19adc1404 0x102b97db8 0x102b995fc 0x102ba7a6c 0x1938d0c30 0x1938cb0e8 0x1938ca200 0x1a99c5598 0x196190004 0x1961955d8 0x100fe9248 0x1935a9598)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<CFRunLoopSource 0x1044d1840 [0x1e13d5b40]>{signalled = No, valid = Yes, order = 0, context = <SCNetworkReachability RLS> {target = 0x10bcf8f80}}: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: outputVolume
Observed object: <AVAudioSession: 0x10444d5a0>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 1;
}
Context: 0x0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I thought this function was only for the old version of KVO implementation?

Comment: You may be right.  I was basing my comment on the method mentioned in the error message.